# "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'" in SQL Server in from clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT 
   [EmpNum], [EmpEmergencyContact], [Relation], [PhType], [Phone] 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        [EmpNum], [EmpEmergencyContact], [Relation], [PhType], [Phone] 
    FROM [EMERGENCY_CONTACT])
```

A simple query where I have a `SELECT` statement within `FROM` clause returns an error:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: Your title doesn't match the error in your post. Also, I see no `where` clause.

Comment: Please read [the documentation on subquery fundamentals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 Decent question, not sure why it is downvoted

Comment: How is this a decent question? The title has nothing to do with the question's content, and even the error message is different.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: The error in the title is what you get when you run this as part of a bigger query. You can tell that the OP put in the effort to post only the relevant part of this query.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to put an alias on the from statement.

So change this:

```
   FROM [EMERGENCY_CONTACT]
)
```

To this:

```
   FROM [EMERGENCY_CONTACT]
) AS tbl
```

Like this:

```
SELECT [EmpNum], [EmpEmergencyContact], [Relation], [PhType], [Phone] 
FROM (
    SELECT [EmpNum], [EmpEmergencyContact], [Relation], [PhType], [Phone] 
    FROM [EMERGENCY_CONTACT]
) AS tbl
```

Even safer would be to use the alias on the columns like this:

```
SELECT 
    tbl.[EmpNum], 
    tbl.[EmpEmergencyContact], 
    tbl.[Relation], 
    tbl.[PhType], 
    tbl.[Phone] 
FROM (
    SELECT [EmpNum], [EmpEmergencyContact], [Relation], [PhType], [Phone] 
    FROM [EMERGENCY_CONTACT]
) AS tbl
```

Comment: @Rajesh123 : No problem. Do that

Comment: it is working and let me try with my original Query..:)

Comment: @Rajesh123 : Do that and let me know